# Please help with this cipher

Tags: cipher

Lets=13px go bois=13px 
Hint: 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 70 61 73 74 65 62 69 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 65 46 48 46 4b 52 33 4d

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a cipher of your creation. Please provide its source.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer... ?**
Well, we may as well start somewhere —

> Converting the hint from hexadecimal to ASCII characters yields
>
>  "https://pastebin.com/eFHFKR3M"
>
>  Converting the contents of this paste from binary to ASCII characters yields
>
>  "https://pastebin.com/K2nvTUDY" (yet another paste!)
>
>  This new paste looks like a JavaScript that's base64 decoding some strings. Decoding these, we get the following three strings.
>
>  1. `password: what a nerd`
>  2. `Thanks for joining the raffle`; and...
>  3. `Add me on steam: http://www.steamcommunity.com/id/azapattaz and https://steamcommunity.com/id/AzaPattazTrading/`

The last bit sounds like some kind of promotion (?) — not sure if that is allowed on Puzzling.SE.